# Alternate History: What would an Inuit Empire look like?

Tags: technology, alternate-history

Brunt of the question in the title. Given that some Inuit decide to settle in one place, ideally Iceland or Kamchatka, the Arctic is still a terrible place to develop technology. If they had imperialist ambitions and the tech to pull it off, Where would they go next and why?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? In an alternative history you have to be really specific about changing single details so that the new reality still resembles history and we can give you good answers, this as it stands is far too broad.

Comment: Hopefully this edit improved it. Have a bit of an issue grounding my questions!

Comment: I'm actually also quite interested in this question. (Have an upvote. :D )

Comment: As they say, "necessity is the mother of invention", and available resources is probably the father... If the tribe can get by on caribou, deer, seals, and an occasional whale, and live the life they want comfortably, then they might stay stagnate for centuries. If they happened to settle on a trade route, then outside ideas might get things started, or near a natural resource deposit like coal or metal, someone might get some ideas of what to do with it. As is, you can likely decide what you want to happen and then extrapolate what needs to change, and then make a new question that isnt broad

Comment: That said, you may want to clarify if you have specific end goals. Are you asking what an small Inuit nation might look like after settling in the south for a few hundred years? Or are you asking about what a more advanced culture using (at least mostly) Inuit materials and technology that grew out of traditional Inuit tech might look like?

Comment: Your second question sounds like what I'm gunning for. I'm looking at a heavily maritime culture that's at least close to industrial. Given their environment, do you think they'd figure out steam technology?

Comment: @adb1: No, if you mean is anything like a steam engine. I'd look at advanced stone age civilizations like the Mesoamericans, Inca, and moundbuilders instead. The old norse also lived in similar climates, and some of them practiced agriculture that leaned heavily on animal husbandry and herding, as your civ presumably would if you wanted to retain a lot of the culture. The Inuit also aren't enormously far off from the Iroquois, who had a thriving culture.

Comment: Intuits have a few big impediments in their development - agriculture is not really possible, mining is very hard and materials like canvas and wood have a very low availability. They can develop ironworking, but should they discover more hospitable lands, to continue development they would need to colonize those lands.

Comment: Not quite a steam engine, but internal heating and crude powered devices. I know that the steam engine came about largely as a means of pumping air into deep mines in the UK. Is metalworking far off for these guys? I'm not quite imagining suits of armour, but maybe just advanced enough that these techno-Inuit act as the Arab traders did in the Silk Road for the whaling, fishing and sea transport industries across the North Atlantic... or further?is that possible?

Comment: Alexander, do you think that these guys would then become aggressive/colonial?

Comment: @adb1 - yes, this is always the possibility with expansionist cultures.

Comment: I think that a good way to improve this question is to think about what changes would lead to the Inuit creating an empire and, following those threads, figure out what that empire would look like.  Then post a question asking people to point out flaws in your empire design.

Comment: If they had imperialist notions, they'd go somewhere warmer.  We'd call them vikings,  until they settled then they'd be called Normans,  or Russians, or Danes